# Objects tree from arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, tree

Sample input:

```
const input = [
  ['Item 1'],
  ['Item 1', 'Item 2'],
  ['Item 1', 'Item 3'],
  ['Item 1', 'Item 4', 'Item 5'],
  ['Item 8', 'Item 9'],
  ['Item 10', 'Item 11', 'Item 12', 'Item 13']
]
```

I need to get a tree like this:

```
const output = [
  { 
    name: 'Item 1', 
    path: 'Item 1',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Item 2',
        path: 'Item 1, Item 2'
      },
      {
        name: 'Item 3',
        path: 'Item 1, Item 3'
      },
      {
        name: 'Item 4',
        path: 'Item 1, Item 4',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Item 5',
            path: 'Item 1, Item 4, Item 5'
          }
        ]
      },
    ] 
  },
  {
    name: 'Item 8', 
    path: 'Item 8',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Item 9',
        path: 'Item 8, Item 9'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Item 10',
    path: 'Item 10',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Item 11',
        path: 'Item 10, Item 11',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Item 12',
            path: 'Item 10, Item 11, Item 12',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'Item 13',
                path: 'Item 10, Item 11, Item 12, Item 13'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried:

```
let data = Object.fromEntries(arrays.map(el => [el[0], { name: el[0], path: `${el[0]}` }]))

for (let arr of arrays) {
  let datNow = data[arr[0]]
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!datNow.hasOwnProperty('children'))
      datNow.children = [
        {
          name: arr[i],
          path: `${arr[i]},${datNow.name}`
        }
      ]
    else if (!datNow.children.some(el => el.name == arr[i])) {
      datNow.children.push({
        name: arr[i],
        path: `${arr[i]},${datNow.name}`
      })
    }

    datNow = datNow.children.find(el => el.name == arr[i])
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(data))
```

But this option does not save the path beyond two parents. The other variants either throwing error, or generated completely wrong tree

As I understand it is possible to do this with a recursive function call, but I can not either generate the tree correctly, or the attribute "path". What could be the solution to this issue?

Comment: You should show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the data and the path to the leaves.

```js
const
    input = [['Item 1'], ['Item 1', 'Item 2'], ['Item 1', 'Item 3'], ['Item 1', 'Item 4', 'Item 5'], ['Item 8', 'Item 9'], ['Item 10', 'Item 11', 'Item 12', 'Item 13']],
    tree = input
        .reduce((r, names) => {
            names.reduce((level, name, i) => {
                let object = (level.children ??= []).find(q => q.name === name);
                if (!object) {
                    const path = names.slice(0, i + 1).join(', ');
                    level.children.push(object = { name, path });
                }
                return object;        
            }, r);
            return r;
        }, { children: [] })
        .children;

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```